# Capybara test reverse proxied domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm currently working on a rails application which has an interesting setup.

We have two applications running on heroku. One is a basic app which works as a reverse proxy, it has multiple domains attached to it and it reverse proxies to our main application which is a rails application ( this application does a look up based on the host then for the routing ).

The reason for this setup is to allow custom domains pointing to "shop pages" on the main application, these shop pages then point back to the original domain for a checkout.

Maybe an example will better explain it, 2 domains:
seller.com
platform.com

platform.com represents the app host for the main application, seller.com is a domain routed through the reverse proxy.
On seller.com you choose your products and then ultimately you check out on platform.com

We're struggling to find a way to test this end to end flow in our main application using capybara given the multiple domains, is there any way to handle this by spoofing the reverse proxy or just using multiple hosts?

The capybara configuration I've tried is below

```
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.allow_unknown_urls
  config.ignore_ssl_errors
  config.skip_image_loading
  config.raise_javascript_errors = true
  config.allow_url("lvh.me")
  config.allow_url("*.lvh.me")
  config.allow_url("testdomain.me")
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.always_include_port = true
  config.javascript_driver = :webkit
  config.default_max_wait_time = ENV.has_key?("CI") ? 60 : 10
  config.app_host = "http://lvh.me"
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SubdomainHelper, type: :feature

  config.before(type: :request) do
    host! "lvh.me"
  end

  config.before(type: :feature) do
    default_url_options[:host] = "http://lvh.me:#{Capybara.server_port}"
  end
end
```

and then in the test I've tried both `visit "http://testdomain.me"` and setting capybara host to be testdomain `Capybara.config.host = "http://testdomain.me"` ( not sure how this approach would work anyway because I need both domains working at the same time )

Comment: Many people test with multiple subdomains, which this is similar to.  What exactly are you having trouble with in trying to set this up?  Please add the Capybara configuration you're trying to use so we have a starting point to figure out what you're doing.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole very good point, sorry for that, have added now

Comment: By default `*.lvh.me` resolves to 127.0.0.1, but testdomain.me does not (but needs to for you to be able to call visit('http://testdomain.me/...') and have it connect to your app under test).  Have you configured your /etc/hosts file or local dns server to resolve testdomain.me to 127.0.01 ?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I havent but I had thought about that, my concern was how can I make that setup work on something like CircleCi?

Comment: You can add domain names to /etc/hosts on CircleCI (every other CI provider has a way to override DNS too) - https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/ - search for /etc/hosts in that page for examples

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 0):

All the domains and subdomains you are using need to be setup to resolve to the ip address(es) your AUT is accessible at. This would generally involve editing your `/etc/hosts` or configuring a local DNS server to report the correct ip.